# Why is a margin-top percentage using height and how can I work around it?

Tags: html, css, margin, reflow

I have a CSS slide down menu that can vary in the number of elements displayed.

I use an `overflow: hidden` wrapper and `margin-top: -100%` to hide the menu, and a CSS transition with `margin-top: 0` to animate the slide down.

The problem appears to be that `margin-top: -100%` seems to be picking up the explicit `width` of any parent element and ignoring the content height.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outer > .slide {
  margin-top: -100%;
  transition-property: margin-top;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.outer:hover > .slide {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.outer.bug {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="slide">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Ayy
      </li>
      <li>
        Bee
      </li>
      <li>
        See
      </li>
      <li>
        Dee
      </li>
      <li>
        Eee
      </li>
      <li>
        Eff
      </li>
      <li>
        Gee
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer bug">
  <div class="slide">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Ayy
      </li>
      <li>
        Bee
      </li>
      <li>
        See
      </li>
      <li>
        Dee
      </li>
      <li>
        Eee
      </li>
      <li>
        Eff
      </li>
      <li>
        Gee
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Run that snippet and you should see two red boxes, mouse over either to get the slide down menu.

The problem is the second box - the only difference is that the parent has `width: 100px;` set.

If you inspect the second box you should see that the `margin-top: -100%;` has been calculated as -100px.

In fact any explicit or inherited width against the parent div will become the negative margin.

The only way I've found round it is to explicitly set the `margin-top` to be the same as the height of the sliding menu, but that involves DOM layout and JS that I don't really want to do for each menu.

Is this a bug in how browsers handle negative percentages on margin-top? IE11, Chrome and FX all seem to treat it the same way.

Is there a better way around it that doesn't require an explicit height calculation and additional Javascript?

Comment: This is how margins are defined in CSS. `margin-top`, if given a percentage value, "refer to width of containing block". https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#propdef-margin

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Ah, so it has to use the width (which is inherited) over the height (calculated from a stack of children + the margin) as that would be a circular reference. So then my question becomes: any way around it without the JS calcs?

Comment: So, you can write  margin-top: -160% or more but i don't know if this a good paretics! maybe it' better if use _viewport height_.

Comment: @MarcoRomano-StudioIGS That would still be 160% of the width - it wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Keith I think Marco means to use `vh` units.

Answer (score 1):

To move an element (regardless of it's height) in relation to its own dimensions you can use a `transform:translate()` instead of margin.

So your requirement to move the element up by its own height would require a translation in the Y-axis of -100%. Like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.outer {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.outer > .slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.outer:hover > .slide {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="slide">
    <ul>
      <li>Ayy</li>
      <li>Bee</li>
      <li>See</li>
      <li>Dee</li>
      <li>Eee</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then we can use absolute positioning to remove the child from the document flow.

Comment: Cheers, but that doesn't quite work - the translate leaves the original reflow around the element, so your snipped has the outer red-border div as always expanded.

Comment: Then you'd need absolute positioning and that's an issue because of the `overflow-hidden`. Is that a requirement?

Comment: Yes, although in my snippet it's just a really ugly red border in my actual code the wrapper itself is absolutely positioned and provides UI hints like a drop shadow over the sliding down content until the animation completes.

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top:-100%` works only when we remove border of `20px` assigned `.outer` which is used twice `10px + 10px`. So we can make use of CSS calc() function over-here to get our output.

`ul` has a default `padding-top:40px` so this too is used twice `40px + 40px`, which we have to set to `0px`.

So ul and border is the reason for not working of `margin-top:-100%;`

**Default ul properties :**

```
ul{
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-before: 1em;
margin-after: 1em;
margin-start: 0;
margin-end: 0;
padding-start: 40px;
}
```

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
.outer > .slide {
  margin-top: calc(-26px + (-100%));
  transition-property: margin-top;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  background:#ccc;
}
.outer > .slide > ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.outer:hover > .slide {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.outer.bug {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="slide">
    <ul>
      <li>Ayy</li>
      <li>Bee</li>
      <li>See</li>
      <li>Dee</li>
      <li>Eee</li>
      <li>Eff</li>
      <li>Gee</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer bug">
  <div class="slide">
    <ul>
      <li>Ayy</li>
      <li>Bee</li>
      <li>See</li>
      <li>Dee</li>
      <li>Eee</li>
      <li>Eff</li>
      <li>Gee</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't, the input of the calc is still the width, not the height - try making the list longer than it is wide and the problem appears again.

Comment: @Keith check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fpLc76xw/ I have added few more li and made changes in calc(). Automatically height of second .slide ul got increased and that got subtracted using calc(), it works. But will update as I get output on another solution.

Comment: Getting better, but that only works because the calculation ends up _more_ than the height of the content - select it in the entity inspector and you'll see that it slides up more than the height of the content. This has the effect of a couple of frames' delay on the slide down because it's animating the excess (which won't be noticed by some but will feel sluggish to many without knowing why).